# Android Studio -> AVD Manager -> Camera error Can't connect to the camera using webcam

Tags: android-emulator

I'm trying to use the webcam for an Android emulator but whatever I do I get the `Can't connect to the camera` error.

Programs used:

`Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299`

`Android Studio 3.0.1`

I have tried to start `Android Studio` as Administrator but the error is still there. However when I look at permissions for using the camera I can't see `Android Studio` or `AVD Manager` there. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you figured out how to fix it?

Comment: @Neckster Nope I did not get it to work. Had to use a real phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I managed to solve it by updating the Android Emulator. There was an update available in sdk manager.
After install the update my webcam started working properly on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have set both front and back camera to same hardware device which is webcam0. Try changing back to emulated and it will get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the camera settings (front and back) from **Webcam0 > Emulated**